# Arranging in order with reference to a column

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database, entity-framework

I have a MySQL database table ( i am using entity framework ) like this :
[image]

Here are my codes that i use to retrieve and populate them on WPF :
 CRUD class file :

```
        //Get all records based on ActivityID and TaskID.
    public IList<Model.questionhint> GetRecords(int listTask, int listActivity)
    {
        IList<Model.questionhint> lstRecords = context.questionhints.ToList();
        return lstRecords.Where(a => a.TaskID == listTask && a.ActivityID == listActivity).ToList(); 

    }
```

Code Behind :

```
      public MainWindow2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateQuestion(1, 5);
    }

    private void PopulateQuestion(int activityID, int taskID)
    {
        IList<Model.questionhint> lstQuestionHints = qh.GetRecords(taskID, activityID);

        foreach(Model.questionhint qhm in lstQuestionHints)
        {

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = qhm.QuestionContent;              
            tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            tb.FontSize = 24;
            WrapPanelTest.Children.Add(lbl);

            if (qhm.Option1.Trim().Length > 0 &&
                qhm.Option2.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
                cb.Items.Add(qhm.Option1);
                cb.Items.Add(qhm.Option2);
                cb.Width = 200;
                WrapPanelTest.Children.Add(cb);
            }

        }
    }
```

How it appear on my program :

[image]

As you can see , the questions are all compounded together , i want to separate them based on their questionNo in the above database table ( for example few records with the same questionNo should be compound together.)but i got totally no idea how . I want to separate them like :

> I [comboBox] to have a nap every afternoon.
>
> The sun [comboBox] not move round the earth.

Appreciate any help on this , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     StackPanel sp=new StackPanel();
    foreach(Model.questionhint qhm in lstQuestionHints)
    {
    StackPanel sp1=new StackPanel(){Orientation=Orientation.Horizontal};     
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = qhm.QuestionContent;              
        tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        tb.FontSize = 24;
        sp1.Children.Add(lbl);

        if (qhm.Option1.Trim().Length > 0 &&
            qhm.Option2.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
            cb.Items.Add(qhm.Option1);
            cb.Items.Add(qhm.Option2);
            cb.Width = 200;
            sp1.Children.Add(cb);
        }
       sp.Children.Add(sp1); 
    }
    WrapPanelTest.Children.Add(sp);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for spending time in helping me , really appreciate it man . Now each and every record is being separated line by line. i think i have to change my query so that it group record of the same questionNo together .

Answer (score 1):

Add your controls in a StackPanel instead of WrapPanel.

Comment: Why? sorry new to WPF , i not really sure what each panels does

Comment: StackPanel arranges it children Horizontaly and Vertically, check its property Orientation. By default it is vertical.
WrapPanel wraps the children if their width goes out of available space and it only arrange the chidren horizontally.

Comment: So you will need a StackPanel to add your TextBlock and ComboBox and its Orientation should be Horizontal. Then add this StackPanel to another StackPanel whose Orintation would be Vertical.

Comment: I only have a WrapPanel that covers the whole Window. can panel be added/created in code behind?

Comment: Using WrapPanel as root container is not a good practice, you better go with Grid as root container. Yes whatever you do in XAML can be done in code behind as well.