# Linq lambda entities , does not contain definition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dao

I have this query code here :

```
//Get all records based on ActivityID and TaskID.
public IList<Model.questionhint> GetRecords1(int listTask, int listActivity)
{
    IList<Model.questionhint> lstRecords = context.questionhints.ToList();
    return lstRecords.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID  }).Where(a => a.TaskID == listTask && a.ActivityID == listActivity).ToList(); 
}
```

The error lies in the `.Where` statement, it says does not contain definition for `ActivityID` and `TaskID`.

Full error :

> 'System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'ActivityID' and no extension method 'ActivityID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am weak in query statements, basically I want to retrieve records from database where activity id = something and task id = something and group them by questionNo, activityId and Task ID .

Comment: btw; if `context` here is a provider like LINQ-to-SQL, EF, etc - then `IList<Model.questionhint> lstRecords = context.questionhints.ToList();` is a ***really*** bad idea - that forces it to load the entire table, before the `where` etc - and to switch to LINQ-to-Objects. I've edited my answer to show how to avoid that

Answer (score 3):

The simplest fix here is: filter (where) before you group; this will also reduce the work that the grouping has to do:

```
return context.questionhints
    .Where(a => a.TaskID == listTask && a.ActivityID == listActivity)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID  })
    .ToList();
```

The reason it isn't working in your original code is, as already mentioned, that `GroupBy` returns a sequence of *groups* - each of which has a `.Key` (your anonymous type) and is itself an `IEnumerable<T>` sequence of the items *in* that group.

However! Your method claims to return `IList<Model.questionhint>`; your *grouped* data is not, and will never be, an `IList<Model.questionhint>` - it will be an `IList<IGrouping<{some anonymous type, Model.questionhint>>`. So: you **cannot** group like that if you are claiming that it is an `IList<Model.questionhint>` - and since the grouping is an anonymous type, you can't change the return type to match. You have two choices:

- don't group
- group by something declarable (a custom type, or a `Tuple<...>`), and change the return type to match

For example:

```
public IList<IGrouping<Tuple<int,int,int>,Model.questionhint>>
        GetRecords1(int listTask, int listActivity)
{
    return context.questionhints
        .Where(a => a.TaskID == listTask && a.ActivityID == listActivity)
        .GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID))
        .ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: @user2376998 ah; no, the error lies in return the wrong shape of data - I will clarify in an edit

Answer (score 2):

change it to `Where(a => a.Key.TaskID == listTask && a.Key.ActivityID == listActivity)`

You are dealing with an IGrouping, of which the Key property is the anonymous object `new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID  }`

This solves the original error, but now we are trying to return IGroupings, which is not the correct return type. A cleaner way of doing it would be

```
var groups = lstRecords.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID  }).Where(a => a.Key.TaskID == listTask && a.Key.ActivityID == listActivity);
IList<Model.questionhint> questionHints = new List<Model.questionhint>();
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    questionHints.AddRange(group);
}
return questionHints;
```

Note, this code is untested. You can do all this in one linq line (as im sure Mark will), however i tend to split it for readability

**Alternative**

If your goal is to get all the questionHints that match the criteria, what is wrong with a simple Where clause?

```
lstRecords.Where(a=>a.TaskID == listTask && a.ActivityID == listActivity).ToList();
```

**References**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx

Comment: thanks for the fast reply , after doing the above i had this error :Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,iStellar.Model.questionhint>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<iStellar.Model.questionhint>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The issue is that the Where clause returns an IEnumerable<IGrouping>> (ignoring the types). IGrouping IS IEnumerable, but even if we simplify it turns into IEnumerable<IEnumerable>, you need to aggregate them all together before you return it. This will resolve the problem for now, however it is far from the most efficient way (or readable way) to do this.

Comment: Its because my database hv many records that belongs to the same questionNo , taskid and activityid , so i need to group them in order to separate them . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584451/arranging-in-order-with-reference-to-a-column this is my table

Comment: If you want them grouped, you cant return an IList<>. If you want to separate them after, group them after this function is returned. Otherwise the effort of grouping them is lost (you ungroup them again when you return them as a List)